# exportar datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

lo que quiero es que aparezcan los botones de exportar pdf , excel etc que trae por defaul el datatable este es mi codigo

```
   //datatable
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#eventos').DataTable({
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         button[
         'copyHtml5',
         'excelHtml5',
         'csvHtml5',
         'pdfHtml5'
         ],
         "scrollY":true,
          "scrollX":true
      });
  });
```

y estas mis librerias

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
    <!-- data table exporting-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

pero la tabla me aparece asi 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias hacer algo asi:

```
<div id="buttons"></div>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan='4'>User</th>             
                <th>Start </th>
                <th>Basic</th>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th> date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>

  </tbody>
    </table>
```

Defines la tabla y el div donde se colocaran los buttons, ahora el javascript:

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();

 var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
     buttons: [
       'copyHtml5',
       'excelHtml5',
       'csvHtml5',
       'pdfHtml5'
    ]
}).container().appendTo($('#buttons'));
```

El resultado:

[image: result]

Puedes revisarlo aca: [buttons datatable](https://jsfiddle.net/4u9L2qkb/1/)

Espero te sirva..!!

Answer (score 0):

Hola para poder tener acceso a los botones de exportación es necesario poner las siguientes rutas:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```